# How to change Jekyll filename format

Tags: ruby, jekyll

I'm using a collection called `now` that takes a date format and lists it newest to oldest. I've determined naming my files `_now/YYYY-MM-DD-title.md` (just like posts) will automatically assign dates to the collection, but I'm *required* to add a title to it. This means my files look like:

```
_now/
  2019-02-28-now.md
  2019-01-15-now.md
  2019-01-01-now.md
  ...
```

I'd prefer if I didn't need to append `-now` to each file.

**Does anyone know how to configure the filename format of a collection?** I'm hoping for something in the configuration options, maybe like:

```
collections:
  now:
    filename: date
```

I'm essentially looking for the opposite of this: [Jekyll Filename Without Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27099427/jekyll-filename-without-date)